# how to login with new key generated with AWSSupport-ResetAccess to Access to my Ec2 Server

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have lost access to my private key for EC2 server on Amazon AWS.
I have followed a few tutorials and found out that we can add new key to existing servers with AWSSupport-ResetAccess.
After following all the process I get a new key created in the "Parameter Store" section.
then i save this key as pem file and access using SSH or create a ppk of this key and connect using putty, I am still unable to access the server and it does not work.
Your help is really appreciated

Comment: Can you login to the EC2 instance using AWS Systems Manager Session Manager?